# Building out custom images (not just pulling a prebuilt image) in a cloud agnostic manor

Tags: terraform, packer

I need to be able to build my own images using {some_tool} alongside Terraform. I had been looking into using packer for this, but it seems to me that it just pulls a prebuilt AMI and configures it.

Basically, I need to build a windows or Linux OS image that will build then deploy with Terraform on any cloud (AWS, VMWARE, OCI, Google, where ever).

Looking for a tool to use this way. Also, I'm not sure how packer is necessary alongside Terraform sense it seems to me that Terraform has the same exact built-in functionality.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems to me that it just pulls a prebuilt AMI and configures it.

You can build AMI's from scratch with the `amazon-ebssurrogate` or `amazon-chroot` builders or use any of the local builders and the `amazon-import` post-processor, but all these options require a lot of understanding of the prerequisites of running the OS on AWS and how to automatically install it from scratch.

> Basically, I need to build a windows or Linux OS image that will build then deploy with Terraform on any cloud (AWS, VMWARE, OCI, Google, where ever).

There is no such thing a cloud agnostic images. Each cloud requires the correct kernel options, drivers, and tools installed to operate optimally or even at all.

> I'm not sure how packer is necessary alongside Terraform sense it seems to me that Terraform has the same exact built-in functionality.

A big difference is that Terraform doesn't handle the lifecycle of creating a AMI. Terraform is not a good tool for creating images from source code, that isn't what it was built for. HashiCorp created these two tools to complement each other.

Comment: Well by clouds agnostic, what I really mean is that I need a single software suit that can be used to build individual images per cloud and per OS.. also the problem issue is that AWS AMIs use latest .net 4.7 and our SW isn’t compatible with 4.7 quite yet.. so we need to be able to install/configure an OS image that has an earlier version of .net

Comment: Also, from what I can see, Packer uses a “source_ami” stanza that just pulls an ami... with that, how is packer creating an ami?

Comment: It launches an EC2 instance based on the source_ami and run provisioning scripts on it, then creates a new AMI from that instance.

Comment: You could just launch a vanilla Windows AMI and uninstall .net 4.7 and install an older version with Packer, and you would have a fully functional AMI with an older version of .net.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcorp's Packer is the perfect tool for this. We build various machine images and deploy them to AWS. Basically packer boots an instance (using the provided base image) in the selected provider, installs the dependencies/requirements as mentioned in your provisioner and create the final image out of it.

So to start the instance, it needs a base image to start with.. So the issue that you mentioned is not an issue at all and it is the way tool works. Hope it helps.

Comment: That does help, thank you. However the specific issue that I am having is that our product is not yet compatible with .net 4.7 and away AMIs use latest .net ... so we need to be able to build an image with an earlier version